# Java Jackson org.codehaus.jackson.map.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException

Tags: java, android, jackson

I am binding a JSON response to my class using Jackson. Everything works great except when there are more fields in my JSON response than my class defines. I want Jackson to ignore the fields that do not exist in my JSON response. This is due to compatability for future versions. If I add a new field I do not want previous versions of my client to crash.

Ideas?

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper(); // can reuse, share globally
        PromoResponse promoResponse = mapper.readValue(r, PromoResponse.class);
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can put the `@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown=true)` annotation on your PromoResponse class.

Answer (score 5):

I believe you would want to do something like this after you declare your mapper object:

```
mapper.configure(DeserializationConfig.Feature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
```

-Dan

Comment: In current release (2.0.4) this config option has slightly changed:
mapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);